# Why does Matlab dbf-reader read certain integers wrong?

Tags: matlab, dbf, dbase

I use the matlab dbf reader available 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112932/how-to-open-dbase-files-dbf-in-matlab)
I've noticed that three digit integers some times are read wrong.

Original data from dbf-file:

> LAMAX,DTLD,1,599,727Q9,A,STANDARD,1,18,18,0,2359.5

But looking at the data in Matlab you see that **599** becomes **995**.
**Why is that?**

> 'LAMAX','DTLD',[1],[995],'727Q9','A','STANDARD','1','18','18','0',
>   [2.3595e+03]

This is how I read the dbf file with matlab code

```
[dbfData, NAMES] = dbfread(path2file);
```

where dbfData is the actual data and NAMES are the field names in the dbf-file.

EDIT:

The dbf-file was created with [INM](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/research/models/inm_model/)

When I open the dbf file using OpenOffice the headers look like this

> METRIC_ID,C,6 ; GRID_ID,C,8I_INDEX,N,3,0 ; J_INDEX,N,3,0 ; ACFT_ID,C,12 ; OP_TYPE,C,1 ; PROF_ID1,C,8 ; PROF_ID2,C,1 ; RWY_ID,C,8 ; TRK_ID1,C,8 ; TRK_ID2,C,1 ; DISTANCE,N,9,1

The distorted integers are stored with 3 digits numbers without decimals **J_INDEX,N,3,0**

Comment: How are you viewing the original data?  What type of field are the integers stored in?  What software created the dbf file?

Comment: You see the answer in the EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used the updated version of STR2DOUBLE2CELL?

From the link above:

*STR2DOUBLE2CELL subfunction sometimes works incorrectly if number of digits in the input parameter is different*